# How to test, in rspec, environment determined with Settings.production?

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra

I have logic in a Sinatra project that determines different behaviour depending on if the environment is production or development.

```
if Services.production?
    # do something
else
    # do something else
end
```

How can I test this code? I have tried the following but it didn't work:

```
expect_any_instance_of(Services).to receive(:production?).and_return(true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an instance of `Services` you're calling `production?` on, it's the `Services` class itself.  You should be able to just do

`expect(Services).to receive(:production?).and_return(true)`

Answer (score 1):

From your code it looks like production? is a class method, so it's not being called on an instance of Services, but rather on the class Services.
Try

```
expect(Services).to receive(:production?).and_return(true)
```

Comment: Thank you. Both answers are correct so I have marked the first as the answer.